# Discord Bot doesn't detect the music (JavaScript Coding)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am in a voice channel and insert "-play tory lanez skrt", however the bot is responding: "You need to add the music you want to listen to!". What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some further information, please (e.g. implementation of the corresponding function)?

Comment: This is the index.js: https://sourceb.in/YGaQ8uc9aM. This is the music bot file: https://sourceb.in/45XnqG29dX. However, I think it has something to do with the packages you need to had in order to make the bot work.